# How to add KeyPressed Event in the same method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, keyevent

I have a problem with this code:

```
 CaptachaKey.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("It works!" + e.getKeyCode());
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 10)
            {
                text = CaptachaKey.getText();
                f.setVisible(false);

            }
        }
    });
```

It doesn't work... 
How can I add this listener in the same class?

Comment: It's `keyPressed` not `KeyPressed`. Anyway use Key Bindings for Swing not Key Listeners.

Comment: @user2820701 for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `KeyListener` use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), for example for code 10:

```
  getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "doSomething");
  getActionMap().put("doSomething",new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("profit");
        }
    });
```

According to your code :

```
CaptachaKey.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "doSomething");
CaptachaKey.getActionMap().put("doSomething",new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            text = CaptachaKey.getText();
            f.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

And when you press `ENTER` key, your code will be executed.